# Using kinect sdk beta 1.0 with kinect for windows

Tags: kinect

I had created a program in C# a while back using Kinect SDK Beta( the first version, not the 2nd).

I now own a Kinect for Windows. My doubt , and a serious one, is that, can I still use Kinect SDK Beta

for making programs for Kinect for Windows ? because I'm in a kind of hurry and i cant afford to change the

entire code again. Please help me out. Or suggest some alternative( easy alternative i mean)

cheers

Prateek

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the SDK beta until June 16, 2016 for non-commercial projects only.

Sources:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2012/01/09/kinect-for-windows-commercial-program-announced.aspx